# DropDownListFor() bindling value AND text to viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a form on a View with a dropdown list, implemented with DropDownListFor(). This View is strongly typed to a ViewModel, which has a SelectList property to hold the options of the dropdown, and then another property to hold the selected value of the dropdown. This is working fine, but what I'd like to do is, hold both the selected value AND selected text of the dropdown in my second property. The reason I want to do this is so that as the form selfposts, I have both the text and value of each selection.

I tried changing the selected value property from an int to a KeyValuePair but only the int part of the pair is set on form submission.

Perhaps there is a better way altogether to accomplish this, I am open to all suggestions including a partial redesign of my methods.

Controller (building SelectList)

```
SelectList leadTypeGroups = new SelectList(_enrollmentRepository.GetLeadTypeGroups(), "Key", "Value");
```

ViewModel

```
public KeyValuePair<int, string> LeadTypeGroupID { get; set; }
public SelectList LeadTypeGroups { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(selected => Model.LeadTypeGroupID, Model.LeadTypeGroups, " ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the sever pull the values from the database (or an in-memory cache) on each request.  Alternatively, have a hidden field with javascript that updates it with the appropriate text whenever the dropdown selection changes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ViewModel to a List and then use a for loop to spit out a drop down for each item in the list.  Something like...

View

```
@for( int i = 0; i < Model.LeadTypeGroupIDs; i++ )
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.LeadTypeGroupIDs[i], Model.LeadTypeGroups, " ")
}
```

ViewModel

```
public List<string> LeadTypeGroupIDs { get; set; }
public SelectList LeadTypeGroups { get; set; }
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain the issue at hand clearly enough. I don't want multiple dropdowns for LeadTypeGroups. This is one dropdown. All I want to do is capture both the selected value AND the selected text in one property in my viewmodel.

Comment: Why?  Your attributes (LeadTypeGroup) should be stored in your database, and you should be using the Id - why do you need the text as well?

Comment: Good question. After my initial View posts the form, I do some processing, but do not commit the form values to the database. The View HttpPost calls a second View (by using RedirectToAction) which brings up a confirmation page. This confirmation page needs to redisplay the chosen values from the first View, along with the results from the backend processing. The confirmation page, once submitted will actually commit the changes to the database.

Comment: Your confirmation page should also pull the text from the db

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that but it seems a waste to call back to the DB when I already have those values at hand. Is there no way to bind the "Text" (along with the Value also) of a dropdown to my ViewModel?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I think you'll have to put a hidden field in your form and then write some javascript that sets that field to match the text from the drop down.

Comment: @Robert Levy I went with pulling the text from the db, hidden field logic was too messy. I could have written a custom Html helper to handle this (according to other SO answers) but that was overkill. Seems this issue is a MVC3 deficiency in Model -> View binding scenarios. If you want, post your idea to just pull from db (since this can't be accomplished by binding) and ill mark as answer.