# Passing in more than one value from a DropDown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to pass in 2 values from the DropDown to the Action method :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMemberToEvent"))
{
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlPeopleList", 
       new SelectList(Model.PeopleList, "Id", "Username"), "Select: ", 
       new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", eventID = Model.catID })
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMemberToEvent(string ddlPeopleList, string eventID) 
{
```

The ddlPeopleList parameter works, . . and I'm a little confused on what that first  parameter is for the DropDown list, . . ., is it the name of the DropDown or is it the Selected value used by the code?

The eventID is not being passed in. I put a break point at the dropdown and the correct value was there, it's just not being passed to the method.
Is there a better way to implement this? thanks

UPDATE : I solved it by doing this. Using a hidden field :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddMemberToEvent"))
            {
                @Html.Hidden("eventID", Model.catID )
```

Comment: EventID is an HtmlAttribute and, as far as I know, it would not be passed back to the controller.  Looks similar to what is being asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143320/dropdownlistfor-bindling-value-and-text-to-viewmodel

Comment: Also, could you explain why you would want more than one value returned, when a drop down list only has one value that is selected?

Comment: I need 2 parameters passed in the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different constructor of Html.DropDownList is all down to the model binding in the controller action side.

In the action, we have code to populate a List

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Action", Value = "0" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Drama", Value = "1" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Comedy", Value = "2", Selected = true });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Science Fiction", Value = "3" });
            ViewBag.MovieType = items;
            return View();
        }
```

In the client side, first consider the easiest constructor which got 1 parameter which is the name of the dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownList("MovieType")
```

When it is rendered, the html is

```
<select id="MovieType" name="MovieType"><option value="0">Action</option>
<option value="1">Drama</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">Comedy</option>
<option value="3">Science Fiction</option>
</select>
```

see here the id and name tag of the select is MovieType, when it is posted to the action, the model binder will try to bind the value of this select to a property named MovieType in the target binder object.

Now consider a little bit complex one

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MovieType)
```

the html for it is:

```
<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown"><option value="0">Action</option>
<option value="1">Drama</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">Comedy</option>
<option value="3">Science Fiction</option>
</select>
```

note that the only difference is the id and name tag, it changes the behaviour of model binder which this time it is gonna find the property of dropdown in the target binding object.

now lets see the most complicated scenario which the constructor have 4 parameters.

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown1", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MovieType, "Movie Type", new { xxx = "abc" })
```

Html part:

```
<select id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1" xxx="abc">
<option value="">Movie Type</option>
<option value="0">Action</option>
<option value="1">Drama</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">Comedy</option>
<option value="3">Science Fiction</option>
</select>
```

id and name is dropdown1, html attribute is xxx and value of xxx is abc. Movie Type is inserted into the first place of into the selectlistitem collection and the value is empty.
Model binder will try to bind dropdown1 to target binding object.

To answer your second question, the model binder will not retrieve value from html attribute that's why eventId is not populated.

Comment: thanks for the explanation,  ..  so the first parameter doubles as a name/id and selected field. I found a solution by adding a hidden field.